# Elm mismatch in view list

Tags: types, elm

```
type Msg
    = NoOp
    | RequestDate
    | ReceiveDate Date
    | UpdateYouTubeUrl YouTubeUrl

-- -

root : Maybe YouTubeUrl -> Html Msg
root youTubeUrl =
    case youTubeUrl of
        Just youTubeUrl ->
            div []
                [ player youTubeUrl
                , urlInput
                ]

        Nothing ->
            urlInput


player : YouTubeUrl -> Html Msg
player youTubeUrl =
    h1 [] [ text ("YouTube player for " ++ youTubeUrl ++ " goes here") ]


urlInput : Html (YouTubeUrl -> Msg)
urlInput =
    input
        [ placeholder "(Enter a YouTube embed URL and hit <Enter>)"
        , onSubmit UpdateYouTubeUrl
        ]
        []
```

That gives me a Type mismatch error:

```
-- TYPE MISMATCH ---------------------------------- ./src/YouTubePlayer/View.elm

The 1st and 2nd entries in this list are different types of values.

28|                 [ player youTubeUrl
29|>                , urlInput
30|                 ]

The 1st entry has this type:

    Html (Msg)

But the 2nd is:

    Html (YouTubeUrl -> Msg)

Hint: It looks like a function needs 1 more argument.

Hint: Every entry in a list needs to be the same type of value. This way you
never run into unexpected values partway through. To mix different types in a
single list, create a "union type" as described in:
<http://guide.elm-lang.org/types/union_types.html>

Detected errors in 1 module.
```

The error is pretty clear that the problem is that I have a list of

```
[ Html Msg
, Html (YouTubeUrl -> Msg)
]
```

... where lists in Elm need to be homogenous, but what I don't understand is why `Html (YouTubeUrl -> Msg)` is the type signature for `urlInput`. I gather it has something to do with my use of `onSubmit`.

I'm an Elm newbie here so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The [Elm Guide book](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/union_types.html) doesn't have any type examples that look like `Html (a -> Msg)` that I saw.

---

`elm 0.18`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem originates in your use of [`onSubmit`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html-Events#onSubmit), whose signature is this:

```elm
onSubmit : msg -> Attribute msg
```

You are passing it a constructor, `UpdateYouTubeUrl`, which takes a single parameter. In order to make a `Msg` using `UpdateYouTubeUrl`, you have to pass a parameter of type `YouTubeUrl`. That parameter is not being passed, so Elm's compiler is telling you that the `urlElement` function needs a `YouTubeUrl` parameter.

My hunch is that you meant to use `onInput`, which accepts a string value as input, which you'd use by getting the targetValue of the input. Plus, `onSubmit` usually goes on a form element wrapping the inputs.

For the most part, if the Elm compiler is telling you that it's looking for a view function that has the return value of `Html (a -> msg)`, it probably means you missed an argument somewhere in the function, since your view should usually be of type `Html Msg` (except for more advanced cases, of course).

Comment: Ahh, I see the difference now. I was going to wrap `onSubmit` in a form, since I don't want to fire `onInput` but rather on an Enter key press; figured the easiest way was to hook into an `onSubmit`.

Comment: Do you mind posting an example of how to do this with `onSubmit` please?